# JQuery Mobile CSS turning entire page black in Jelly Bean

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, jquery-mobile

My mobile site template uses the jQuery Mobile CSS and on the latest Android Phones, it only loads the first 20 pixels or so of the page and the rest of the page appears as a black screen.

If I remove the jquery mobile CSS line, the 'black box' effect goes away so I am guessing the problem lies there but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

I am able to recreate the problem using Eclipse, so here is a screenshot:
http://minus.com/l1wCMXzWbsHZ1

It looks fine on an iPhone, the DroidX, and 2 Android Tablets I have had access to, but on the Samsung Galaxy Note and newer droids they get the 'black box.'

You can see a demo of it here:
http://revivelab.com/demo_software/mobilebug/

Here is my source code:

```
<?php
    // this function detects mobile tags in the ua string
    function detect_mobile(){
        if(preg_match('/(alcatel|amoi|android|avantgo|blackberry|benq|cell|cricket|docomo|elaine|htc|iemobile|iphone|ipad|ipaq|ipod|j2me|java|midp|mini|mmp|mobi|motorola|nec-|nokia|palm|panasonic|philips|phone|playbook|sagem|sharp|sie-|silk|smartphone|sony|symbian|t-mobile|telus|up\.browser|up\.link|vodafone|wap|webos|wireless|xda|xoom|zte)/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
    <head profile="http://www.w3.org/2000/08/w3c-synd/#">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="generator" content="Revive Media Services" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <title></title>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" name="viewport" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/core.css" media="screen"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/handheld.css" media="handheld, only screen and (max-device-width:480px)"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/dkmtwo.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <!-- start of home page -->
            <div data-role="page" id="one">
                <!-- home page header -->
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
                    <div style="background-color:#fff;width:100%;height:125px;background-repeat:repeat-x;">
                        <div style="width:254px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                            <div style="width:254px;text-align:center;">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/254x125" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!-- /header -->

                <!-- home page content -->
                <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
                    <div style="background-color:#bec7ce; background-image: url('img/barbg.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat-x; padding:15px 0px 5px 0px;text-align:center;border-bottom:1px solid #666;">
                            <div style="text-align:center;">
                                <span style="width:140px;">
                                    <a href="tel:1234567890" class="phonelink" style="font-size:20px;text-decoration:none;">(123) 123-4567</a> 
                                </span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width:100%;background-color:#102847;" >
                        <div style="width:320px;background-color:#fff;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:left;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                            <h2 style="color:#23ae4c;text-align:center;">Headline!</h2>
                            <div style="float:right;">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/100x115" />
                            </div>
                            <p class="content" style="line-height:24px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            <a href="http://forecastbudget.com/?view=nomobile" rel="external" data-role="button" data-theme="b">View Our Full Site</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /content -->

                <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" style="border:0;border-bottom:10px solid #414141;">
                    <div style="background-color:#bec7ce; background-image: url('img/barbg.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat-x; padding:10px;padding-top:20px;text-align:center;">
                        <a href="http://example.com/?view=nomobile" rel="external" data-theme="b" style="color:#3161a1;text-decoration:none;">example.com</a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /footer -->
            </div><!-- /home page -->


            <div class="clear"></div>

            <?php
                $mobile = detect_mobile();
                if($mobile === true){
                    echo '1';
                }else{
                    echo '2';
                }
            ?>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: it's okay for me in chrome on XPeria Z

Comment: Does anyone else notice when resizing the height really fast in chrome you sometimes get a black background? If only there was a way to inspect it before it disappears... Edit: on my Android apparently it's also a clickthrough element. So weird...

Comment: As I trouble shoot it, I'm starting to think it's a problem with the HTML markup itself, like maybe jQuery is encountering an error parsing it into the mobile view?

Comment: Checkout my answer and let me know your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the PHP at the bottom was actually the culprit. Removing this fixes it:

```
        <?php
            $mobile = detect_mobile();
            if($mobile === true){
                echo '1';
            }else{
                echo '2';
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: I imagine the reason is because it wasn't wrapped in a container of data-role="page"

Comment: so you are saying that `<html><body><div id="container">1</div></body></html>` breaks your render? weird, it shouldn't

Comment: It totally does; we actually had this bug on 6 live sites and we were able to go in and fix each one by simply removing that PHP code. Crazy, I know, but try it with the Android Eclipse simulator and you can recreate it. I'd love to understand more about the 'why' it broke, for sure.

Comment: since you are using jquery mobile.The entire content of the page is supposed to be wrapped in a div having data-role as page.Otherwise pages break.

Answer (score 3):

As TecHunter has suggested I think you should include all of your necessary js an css files in between

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_id">


</div>
```

As jquery mobile loads only pages div while executing the web pages.
You can also refer this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891085/jquery-validations-not-working-without-page-refresh-in-jquery-mobile).Hope it helps.Let us know if it raises any new issues.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving your scripts at the end of your `body` :

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the first three lines with the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Other try: you could try giving a **type** to your scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

And/or giving another doctype to your document, **HTML5**, as @Venkat suggests or **XHTML Transitional** as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I don't know if this will solve for sure your problem, but always is better have properly validated markup.